# Where can I get 5.45.7 security release

Tags: lts

5.45.0 was released on 2022-01-05. The latest patch revision is 5.45.7 (2022-06-02).

Where can I get 5.45.7  I cant find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it an [ESR](https://civicrm.org/esr) after [5.45.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/civicrm/files/civicrm-stable/)?  See also [this](https://civicrm.org/comment/10643#comment-10643)